# Forbidden You don't have permission to access /dashboard/ on this server

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, selinux

I was able to reach http://myip, it is redirecting me to apache page.

But when am trying to reach var/www/html/dashboard am having this problem forbidden dont have permissions.

My httpd.conf is as below:

```
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride All
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Further relax access to the default document root:
<Directory "/var/www/html">
```

I have already disabled the SELinux:

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

I have also tried:

```
sudo restorecon -r /var/www/html
```

Nothing is helping me to solve my problem, can somebody please help me:

Comment: Is there a `.htaccess` file in /var/www?

Comment: Hi @JeremyHarris, No, what is .htaccess and how can I configure it.

Comment: When you do `AllowOverride All` in a directory, it means that you can have a file named `.htaccess` in there that has project specific settings. Often times, it is used for things like "pretty URL's" and project specific configuration. I was just curious if there is a file there that is overriding anything.

Comment: Okay, I dont have anything inside www except html folder.

Comment: Is there an htaccess inside the html folder?

Comment: No, there is no htaccess inside the html folder either. Inside html i have a symbolic link to a folder dashboard which consists index.html file and this is what am trying to access from browser. This index.html file consists of the status of my different applications such as tomcat, and will be created by crontab job after every 1 min. So the structre is /var/www/html/ -> dashboard

Answer (score 0):

- Allow the apache user read and execute permissions at every level of your DocumentRoot using chown or chmod at each level that is restricting the apache user.
- Or, FollowSymLinks Option must be enabled for your directory in httpd configuration.

  > ```
  > <Directory "/var/www/html/dashboard">
  >   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  > </Directory>
  > ```
- Or, to diagnose, check file permissions using namei:

  > ```
  > namei -l /var/www/html/dashboard
  > ```